# Populating textarea using ViewBag ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: model, asp.net-core-mvc, textarea, razor-pages, viewbag

I have this textarea that is not being populated. The viewbag is not empty because if I populate a textbox instead, the information in `@ViewBag.JobsDetails.job_description` shows. It just does not show in a textarea

```
<div class="col-lg-6 mb-4">
    <label class="form-label" asp-for="job_description"></label>
    <textarea class="form-control" asp-for="job_description">@ViewBag.JobsDetails.job_description</textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Textarea does not display value when it has an asp-for parameter](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/14428) we can see:

> The behavior you're observing here is by-design.
> asp-for purposefully overwrites the content of the text area.

And below are two options you can refer:

**Option 1**.use `name` attribute not `asp-for` like:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 mb-4">
         <label class="form-label" asp-for="job_description"></label>
         <textarea class="form-control" name="job_description">@ViewBag.JobsDetails.job_description</textarea>
   </div>
```

**Option 2**.you can pass the model to the view like:

In Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
 {

     ViewBag.JobsDetails = new JobsDetails()
     {
         job_description = "Steve"
        
     };
     var model = ViewBag.JobsDetails;
     return View(model);
 }
```

In the view:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 mb-4">
         <label class="form-label" asp-for="job_description"></label>
         <textarea class="form-control" asp-for="job_description"></textarea>
   </div>
```

result:
[image]

Comment: I used option two with some adjustments. Client-side validation doesn't work with option 1